# How to update value of a variable in different script file?

Tags: python

I have following files:

```
/home/Tester/Test.py
/home/Manager/Manage.py
```

Manage.py has a following variable:

```
MyTest = 0
```

Now, from Test.py, I need to set the value of MyTest variable to 100.

In Test.py I have following imports

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../Manager')
import Manage as M

M.MyTest = 100
```

The value is not getting updated in the Manage.py file.
That is I expect the following changes in Manage.py:

```
MyTest = 100
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What makes you think it's not getting updated? Is there a function in the `Manage` module you can call to print the value of `MyTest`?

Comment: Do you expect the file to be modified by that code?!

Comment: It is not getting updated because I am checking the contents of the file after running the code. There are no functions in Manage.py. It has variables whose values can be used elsewhere. Sort of like global variables that can be used by all.

Comment: @frederick99 Yes, I expect the value of MyTest in Manage.py to be set to 100 from 0.

Comment: The file is imported into the python interpreter. You can't then modify the original file by modifying the interpreter's memory.

Comment: You're misunderstanding something pretty fundamental about how python, source files and the runtime in general works. Imagine the files are identical to typing the code in by hand into the REPL. If you type in `test = 100` and then `test = 0`, would you expect the first line to magically change to `test = 0` _on your screen_?

Comment: @pvg indeed, I can't think of any language that dynamically modifies source code like that. I mean, you can write code to modify the source code in a file...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga We can do that in Java. Have a public variables stored in different files. Update their value based on importing the package.

Comment: @hshantanu no, the source code in the file does *not* get changed in Java. You can do that in any language, pretty much, by writing code that modifies the source code, but I don't know why you would want to do that or what you are expecting. Perhaps we are not speaking of the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The variable's value change, takes effect on memory level and not on script file.